# Why are metatables necessary in Lua?

Tags: c++, oop, lua

I'm a C++ programmer learning Lua, trying to understand why getmetatable() and setmetatable() are needed.

According to all the tutorials, if I want to make a "subclass" from a "baseclass" (To use C++ concepts) somewhere in my subclass definition, I will have something like this:

```
1) setmetatable(subclass, getmetatable(baseclass))
```

but why? Why not just do:

```
2) setmetatable(subclass, baseclass)
```

or why not just copy all the base class members into the subclass and to heck with metatables?

```
3) for k,v in pairs(baseclass) do
    subclass[k] = v 
end
```

After all, OOP conceptually, all I am trying to do is make my subclass be a type of baseclass, and then add some differences. So I start by first being a copy of the baseclass and then do my modifications that make my subclass different.

Then it dawned on me that maybe metatables are **shared** instances. That is, classes with the same metatables share the **exact same metatable in memory**. Is that right? If I change a data element in a single metatable, all the tables that have that metatable will experience the same change in data? If I have a "counter" variable in a metatable and increment it, all the classes that use that metatable will have that member variable be incremented.

And that's the difference that is not made clear in all the tutorials and what makes metatables so confusing. So metatables, in C++ terms, are **static** members of the classes that share them.

But approach 3 above will still accomplish the goal but wastefully because it creates copies of the baseclass members instead of sharing them.

So, is this a valid function to create subclasses? (duplicate a base class then add new members to make it different than that base class)

```lua
local Developer = subclass(Person, { skillz = {"c++", "lua", "python"}})

function subclass(base, new_members)
    local self = {}
    setmetatable(self, getmetatable(base))
    local mt = getmetatable(self)
    for k,v in pairs(base) do -- replicate bases members that aren't in its metatable into us as our metatable
        mt[k] = v
    end
    for k,v in pairs(new_members) do  -- add new members or overrides that make us different than base!
        mt[k] = v
    end
    return self
end
```

Comment: Lua doesn't have inheritance; it has mechanisms, upon which you can *build* inheritance. As such, there are *several* ways of making "derived classes" in Lua. You're talking about one part of a single way of doing it. Whether it makes sense depends entirely on what the rest of that way of implementing inheritance is. What is `baseclass`, and what is its metatable? Without that, we can't really know.

Comment: I think the essence of this, my question is, really, "Are metatables shared between tables that use them, I mean shared exactly as in, the exact same instance?" For which I can just write a quick code snippet to find out but I was also looking for perhaps some caveats and gotchas.

Comment: If you set the same metatable to multiple taes they will reference the same metatable, yes. There are much more powerful reasons metatables are useful, but that's really broad for an SO question.

Comment: Please enumerate the reasons. It's especially important as I'm learning so I take the proper approach from day one.

Comment: Next time you wish to reply to someone on SO you should @ them, @warspyking for instance. You're lucky I came back to this question to see your reply

Comment: As for the reasons, look up everything else metatables can do. They provide the ability to interact with your "objects" in really neat ways.